# Windows Insider Realtek audio driver plays media at 100% volume although slider is fully adjustable

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

The title pretty accurately describes my issue, I just joined the insider programme and I noticed it was updating the Realtek audio driver, after the installation completed, I went to listen to music and had my ears blasted off. The volume slider is fully adjustable and when set to 0, the sound is completely muted, but the volume itself is not adjustable. Prior to upgrading, everything worked fine. I don't see a roll back option on the audio drivers in the device manager, and disabling the driver doesn't do anything.

please help quick, I wanna listen to music!

Edit: I was surprised that this worked because normally the windows default driver updater never finds updates for drivers, but this time it downloaded a new updated driver which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had freshly updated the driver and therefore dismissed it as a possibility, but in the end, updating it worked. Drivers man!